# Can the service-broker cause SQL Server to crash when using SQLDependency

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, service-broker

I have C# application that uses `SQLDependency` to get updates from a message table. I have tested it quite extensively and worked great in the development environment but when I ran it on the production server the server crashed. I can not be absolutely sure that it is this because we picked it up ~10 minutes after I ran the application.

From what I understand from how the `SQLDependency` works it uses stored procedures to interact with the service broker.

The errors I received

> *SQL Server must shut down in order to recover a database (database ID 1). The database is either a user database that could not be shut down or a system database. Restart SQL Server. If the database fails to recover after another startup, repair or restore the database.*
>
> *Could not find an entry for table or index with partition ID 428869310480384 in database 2. This error can occur if a stored procedure references a dropped table, or metadata is corrupted. Drop and re-create the stored procedure, or execute DBCC CHECKDB.*

We are running SQL Server 2005 SP1.

Edit:(removed code the link explains it better) I followed this example and mainly changed the query and what I do with the data.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/156991-using-sqldependency-to-monitor-sql-database-changes/

Comment: I never had that kind of error with SqlDependencies. Does sounds like a different problem. You probably need to investigate further on that error message of yours.

Comment: Can you provide some code or a summary of how you are wiring up the broker to your application?

Comment: Do you run DBCC CHECKDB on a regular maintenance schedule? (you should...)

Comment: @MitchWheat Not that I am aware of, we do full db backups and transaction log backups though. I will have to go look.

Comment: I did a DBCC CHECKDB on all of the databases and none returned with any errors. I did find that db 1 is the master database and db 2 is tempdb.